# group by and count cakephp not returning expected result

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Sql query works fine but in cakephp not returning expected output.

```
SELECT products.product_id, products.product_title, COUNT(posts.post_id)
AS total_post
FROM products
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.product_id = products.product_id
GROUP BY products.product_id
```

cakephp query builder

```
    $products = $this->Product->find('all',array(
        'Product.is_active' => 1,
        'fields'=>array(
            'Product.product_id, Product.product_title,COUNT(Post.post_id) as total_post'
        ),
        'joins'=>array('LEFT JOIN posts as Post ON Post.product_id = product.product_id'),
        'GROUP'=>'Product.product_title'
    ));
```

returning first product title, total post (not product title wise) and posts related to first product

Comment: No offense, but pretty much anything in your options array is wrong. Why would you think that things work that way? For sure the docs nowhere show that what you are doing there could possibly work. **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find** | **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables** | **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html**

Comment: thank you for letting me know that. Going through the docs again

Comment: thanks ndm for pointing that out, solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to cake doc solved it. Query should be like

```
$options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'posts',
            'alias' => 'Post',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Post.product_id = Product.product_id',
            )
        )
    );
    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'Product.is_active' => 1
    );
    $options['fields'] = array(
        'Product.product_id, Product.product_title,COUNT(Post.post_id) as total_post'
    );
    $options['group'] = array(
        'Product.product_title' 
    );
    $options['recursive'] = 0;
    $products = $this->Product->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the example of join with group by and see what you are making wrong

```
 $options = array(
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'fields'=>array('Category.*','COUNT(`Entity`.`id`) as `entity_count`'),
                'joins' => array('LEFT JOIN `entities` AS Entity ON `Entity`.`category_id` = `Category`.`id`'),
                'group' => '`Category`.`id`',
                'contain' => array('Domain' => array('fields' => array('title')))
            );

            return $this->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: see your code you are not passing your conditions to condition array